# Apply functions over (anti-)diagonals

Tags: r, function, apply

We know that `apply()` in `base` can apply a function to margins of an array, and margins should be rows or columns. I want to expand the margins to *"diagonals"* and *"anti-diagonals"*. The structure looks like

```
diagApply <- function(x, FUN, ..., anti = FALSE) {  }
```

I name this function `diagApply` and the argument `anti` is an indicator of *"diagonals"* and *"anti-diagonals"* which `FUN` will be applied over (defaults to `FALSE`). Take a 3x4 matrix for example:

```
mat <- matrix(letters[1:12], 3, 4)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "a"  "d"  "g"  "j" 
# [2,] "b"  "e"  "h"  "k" 
# [3,] "c"  "f"  "i"  "l"
```

Assume that I need to paste elements in each (anti-)diagonal. With an `apply()-like` way, the function should be executed as

```
diagApply(mat, paste, collapse = ".")              # code 1
diagApply(mat, paste, collapse = ".", anti = TRUE) # code 2
```

The expected output will be

```
list("c", "b.f", "a.e.i", "d.h.l", "g.k", "j")  # output of code 1
list("a", "d.b", "g.e.c", "j.h.f", "k.i", "l")  # output of code 2
```

Are there any existing functions achieving that? If not, hope someone can share your idea on this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A similar output to the first one can be achieved by `unlist(lapply(split(mat, row(mat) - col(mat)), paste, collapse = "."))`.

Comment: And `unlist(lapply(split(mat, row(mat) - (ncol(mat) - col(mat) + 1)), paste, collapse = "."))`. Perhaps you can turn that into your function?

Comment: @MartinGal good point! Actually the second output can be done by replacing `row(mat) - col(mat)` in your first comment with `row(mat) + col(mat)`. Anyway so grateful to you.

Comment: `+` was too obvious for me... I guess, I was overthinking that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the other comments, you can do something more general to work from any corner:

```
diagApply(mat, 1, toString)
# [1] "c"       "b, f"    "a, e, i" "d, h, l" "g, k"    "j"      
diagApply(mat, 2, toString)
# [1] "a"       "b, d"    "c, e, g" "f, h, j" "i, k"    "l"      
diagApply(mat, 3, toString)
# [1] "j"       "g, k"    "d, h, l" "a, e, i" "b, f"    "c"      
diagApply(mat, 4, toString)
# [1] "l"       "i, k"    "f, h, j" "c, e, g" "b, d"    "a"
```

Your desired results can be obtained by

```
diagApply(mat, 1, paste, collapse = '.', SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
diagApply(mat, 2, paste, collapse = '.', SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

I'm not sure how important the ordering is for the elements, but you can pass a `rev` to `FUN` if desired.

```
diagApply <- function(X, MARGIN, FUN, ..., SIMPLIFY = TRUE) {
  idx <- switch(
    MARGIN,
    col(X) - row(X),
    row(X) + col(X),
    (col(X) - row(X)) * -1L,
    (row(X) + col(X)) * -1L,
    stop('\'MARGIN\' should be 1, 2, 3, or 4')
  )
  
  res <- unname(lapply(split(X, idx), FUN, ...))
  
  if (!isFALSE(SIMPLIFY) && length(res)) 
    simplify2array(res, higher = (SIMPLIFY == 'array'))
  else res
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter at all, but why not `row(X) - col(X)` and `-row(X) - col(X)` instead of multiplying??

Comment: @MartinGal I think it's because `(col(X) - row(X)) * -1L` more intuitively shows that `MARGIN=3`  starts on the opposite corner of `MARGIN=1`.

Comment: @rawr Thank you so much! I'm surprised that `SIMPLIFY` is also considered in your function. It makes this function resemble those in the apply-family.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is quite similar to the one in @MartinGal comment, only using the function `rev` and the `+` operator between `row(mat)` and `col(mat)` for the anti-diagonal case.

Such a function should do the job

```
diagApply <- function(x, FUN, ..., anti = FALSE) {
  
  if(anti == FALSE)
    res <- unname(lapply(split(mat, col(mat) - row(mat)), FUN, ...))
  
  else
    res <- unname(lapply(lapply(split(mat, col(mat) + row(mat)), rev), FUN, ...))

  return(res)
}
```

The results are indeed equal to your expected output

```
identical(diagApply(mat, paste, collapse = "."),
          list("c", "b.f", "a.e.i", "d.h.l", "g.k", "j"))
# [1] TRUE
identical(diagApply(mat, paste, collapse = ".", anti = TRUE),
          list("a", "d.b", "g.e.c", "j.h.f", "k.i", "l"))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Curious: Why there are two `lapply`'s in your else condition? And `anti == FALSE` can be simplified to `!anti`. :-)

Comment: Because I wanted to apply the function `rev` to each vector of letters contained in the list (as at first they are sorted in reversed order, i.e. `"b.d"` instead of `"d.b"`). Do you think there is a better approach? For the second thing, you are right, sometimes I write the first thing that comes to mind without thinking of a shorter alternative :D

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not aware of any better solution.

Comment: @RicS You are considerate to the ordering but I think `rev()` can be adjusted afterward when I use this function, e.g. `diagApply(mat, function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse = "."))`. Thank you so much! +1